# Android Studio: Early Access Java versions may cause compatibility issues

Tags: java, android, visual-studio-2012, runtime-error

What is the recommended Java version for **Android Studio v1.0.2**?
The official system requirements only specifies JDK 7 for v1.0.2

However, after selecting jdk1.7.0_71 (by navigating through: **Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure**), the Android Studio Welcome page still warns:

> Early Access Java versions may cause compatibility issues. Please use
>   stable release.

I don't know if the Java compatibility is the reason, but Android studio has many bugs, the most consequential being the ineffective OK/Done button in many dialogs of Android Studio!
Eg: After selecting the Eclipse project in the "Import from Non-Android Studio project" dialog, I press the OK button, but the dialog closes without any effect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Android Studio 1.0.2 a JRE above 7 is incompatible.
**Update:**
But as commented by @Jackson:

> Android 1.5.1 works with JRE 8 but complains

The basic logic is that the JDK has nothing to do with Android Studio runtime functioning. Instead, it seems that it uses the Java Runtime environment for Android Studio runtime and the JDK only for the development resources.

This means that even though Android Studio points to a JDK 7, it will still show the "Early access Java versions" error if you have a JRE above 7 (in this case I had JRE 8 installed)

Comment: I also have java 8 installed and do not want to go back to java 7. Any workaround.